# Node.js keeps hanging/loading on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm following this beginner node.js tutorial (http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb) and i have just created my first server using this code:

```
var http = require("http")

http.createServer(

    function(request, response){

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"})
        response.write("hello world")
        response.end

    }


).listen(3333)
```

This works great, but when i go to the url localhost:3333/ i see the words "hello world" very briefly and then it just dissapears.

See this vine for a quick video: https://vine.co/v/MBJrpBEQvLX

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put parentheses at the end of `response.end()`.

The code should read:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer( function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
        response.write("hello world");
        response.end();
    }).listen(3333);
```

Comment: The semi colons have absolutely nothing to do with it. He didn't call `response.end()`, that was the only issue. Javascript is perfectly valid without semicolons in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Put your Hello World in the **[response#end()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)**. I'd also suggest that your read the [**NodeJS API**](http://nodejs.org/api/)

```
http.createServer(function (req, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3333);
```

Comment: thx, i'll read the API, your sollution worked but that was due to the fact that i forgot to call the .end method